# extract text between two markers in a pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas column that contains data like this:

```
function(tb3696,[1,1,1,0],'glpK',"ATP:glycerol 3-phosphotransferase")
function(tb3255,[1,1,1,0],'manA',"mannose-6-phosphate isomerase")
function(tb3441,[1,1,1,0],'mrsA',"phosphoglucomutase or phosphomannomutase")
function(tb118,[1,1,1,0],'oxcA',"oxalyl-CoA decarboxylase")
```

I need to extract the following text from the above column:

```
tb3696
tb3255
tb3441
tb118
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
df[0].str.extract('tion\( (.+?) \,\[',expand=False)
```

Comment: The spaces in the regex have meaning, just remove them `tion\((.+?),\[` https://regex101.com/r/Da3HfW/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
df[0].str.extract(r'\((\w+),', expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rG4Uu9/1).

The regex matches one or more letters/digits/underscores between a `(` and `,` chars. Since `Series.str.extract` requires a capturing group in a regex pattern, there `\w+` is enclosed with two unescape capturing parentheses.